# Xaml Editor in VB.Net Express / Visual Studio: Auto Completion Annoyance

Tags: vb.net, xaml, editor

As I'm typing out Xaml in VB.Net Express 2010, it helpfully finishes certain things for me. Most of the autocomplete is fine, but some of it annoys me and it leads me to wonder if I'm missing something or doing it wrong.

If I type:

```
<GroupBox Header=
```

It automatically puts a quotation mark before *and* after my cursor. I've gotten used to the quotation mark before the cursor - I immediately start typing in whatever property I wanted.

But now there is a quotation mark after my cursor! I have to reach over to the other side of my keyboard and press the right arrow key to move past it. I find this insanely aggravating, because it breaks my "flow" while I'm typing. Are you supposed to be able to press a close-at-hand key (like tab, but that doesn't work) to move to the other side of the quotation mark or do they really intend for you to have to constantly use the right arrow key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it off: Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous -> "Attribute Quotes"

Comment: In my copy of VS2010 Professional Auto Insert is under  XAML -> Miscellaneous

Comment: It's kind of weird that this behaviour doesn't have a "solution", but at least they were nice enough to let you get rid of it...